# git push on openshift removes dynamically created folders and files

Tags: git, openshift

I have an application hosted in an openshift account. The application creates dynamic files and folders in some actions, so when I make any changes in my local repository and I do push to the openshift server, somehow the folders that was created dynamically are removes once the push is done.

Any idea or suggestion about this weird issue?

Comment: have you read openshift documentation about managing files?

Comment: Hi @DRC if you know about some blog or documentation that can help me with my issue please give it to me, I would be grateful

Comment: this could help https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html#__code_data_code

Answer (score 2):

Basically, all the

```
~/app-root/repo
```

contents is wiped on every git push. You can create stuff in

```
~/app-root/logs
```

just mind the name of the folder ;)
If you need something persisting across deployments, it's going to be

```
~/app-root/data
```

This is dedicated for dynamic, persisted data.